# Replacement for RIA Services in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We are moving our application from Silverlight to WPF. We are currently using RIA Services (OpenRIA Services) for the generation of a domain context on the client side. Although it has its drawbacks, the client side entity tracking with changesets and the validation by attributes are really nice.

Is there a framework that could be used as a replacement? Or if we have to implement it ourselves, what approach should we use?

We are open to not using WCF at all, since we have a working N-layer architecture and are simply interested in replacing the service part. So everything goes.

Comment: I am standing in front of the same task just now, can I ask you how did this replacement end up?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Pretty sure the OpenRIA service support desktop applications , you should be able to keep using OpenRIA

The OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client has even made to be portable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have migrated to Open RIA Services and everything works perfect with Silverlight but fails with WPF because the RIA web calls act as if they are "Per Call" not "Per Session". In other words HttpContext.Current lives on with Silverlight web calls, but HttpContext.Current is lost on WPF calls using the same RIA service calls. i.e. HttpContext is lost call to call when calling the services via WPF. I'm not sure why.